# Disable RealityKit/ARKit when building in xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

**Is it possible to disable RealityKit/ARKit/AR when building for xcode Simulator? So that I can style/change non-ar related pages.**

I want to change my home page, adding different sections and styling. The home page has nothing to do with ARKit/Reality Kit, but I don't have the physical device with me.

The errors say that various RealityKit/ARKit functions are undefined or don't exist. Like ARView has no member .occlusion.

The home page has no need for AR at all, is it possible to build and run the simulator, or even preview without a physical (AR Enabled) device?

Comment: Btw plain ARKit is fine. It's RealityKit that doesn't work on simulators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Conditional Compilation Block](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID538), as explained in the Swift Programming Manual:

```swift
class SubclassedARView : ARView {

    var configuration: ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    var runOptions: ARSession.RunOptions()

    init() {

#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)

        // Code here is only compiled when building to a real or generic device. 

        // This is the place where you should add your RealityKit specific
        // code, or at least the code that gives build-time errors in Xcode. 

        // An example of a problematic method:
        session.run(configuration, options: runOptions)

#endif

    }
}
```